# Child-Parent relationship using NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I'm trying to figure out how to make child-parent relationships using NHibernate.
I have two classes Foo and Bar. Foo have a collection of Bars and Bar have reference to parent Foo.

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Bar> Children { get; set; }  
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping of this classes are:

```
  <class name="Foo" table="foos">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="name" />
    <set name="Children" inverse="true" lazy="true">
      <key column="fooId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Bar"/>
    </set>
  </class>

  <class name="Bar" table="bars">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Description" column="description" />
    <many-to-one name="Parent" column="fooId"/>
  </class>
```

This is sesion factory creation:

```
if (_sessionFactory == null)
{
    var configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.Configure();
    configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Foo).Assembly);
    _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

And here is how I'm adding new Foo:

```
        Foo foo = new Foo { Name = "name1" };
        foo.Children = new List<Bar>();
        foo.Children.Add(new Bar { Description = "desc1" });
        foo.Children.Add(new Bar { Description = "desc2" });

        using (ISession session = NHibirnateHelper.OpenSession())
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(foo);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
```

When calling Save(foo) method I have an exception "Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of Test.Foo".
With iinere exception: ""Unable to cast object type \"NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[Test.Bar]\" к типу \"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Test.Bar]\"".

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `ICollection` instead of `List`

Comment: Or use can change `<set name="Children"...></set>` to `<bag name="Children" ...></bag>` and use then `IList` instead of `List`.

Comment: And last but not least: in order to persist also the items from `Children` collection, some more adjustments should be done: set a **cascade** attribute in `<set name="Children" ... cascade="all-delete-orphan">` and set a parent for `Children` items explicitly: `foo.Children.Add(new Bar { Description = "desc1", Parent = foo });`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `public virtual List<Bar> Children { get; set; }` to `public virtual ISet<Bar> Children { get; set; }`. ISet can be found in `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<>`.

You could even try using `IList` instead of `List` and see if it works.Avoid using concrete classes for the collections and try using interfaces so that Nhibernate could inject its own concrete implementations.